# Creating a Dialog Prompt Box from an onEdit Function isn't working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to create a dialog prompt for a Google Sheet File whenever a certain column is edited. The prompt opens whenever I run it by itself manually, but for some reason when I try to run it within the onEdit function, it stops working. As you can see by the code and Logs below, the error seems to happen at the result variable since that's when the Logger stops outputting stuff. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**CODE:**

```
    function onEdit(e){
  
  Logger.log("onEdit");
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  if(sheetName =='Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 23){
      Logger.log("should be running email prompt");
      emailPrompt(); 
   }
 }

function emailPrompt() {
  Logger.log("Reaching email prompt");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  Logger.log("ui");
  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Email Template',
      'Please edit the email:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

      Logger.log("result");
      
      
  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    //Insert Code to select email
    ui.alert('Your name is ' + text + '.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('Email cancelled');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('Email cancelled.');
  }
}
```

**LOGS:**

```
[20-07-10 15:21:09:472 CDT] onEdit
[20-07-10 15:21:11:198 CDT] should be running email prompt
[20-07-10 15:21:11:199 CDT] Reaching email prompt
[20-07-10 15:21:11:201 CDT] ui
```

**EDIT: Setting up installable trigger**

[image]

**EDIT 2:** Setting up an installable trigger worked, so thanks so much! The only problem I have right now is that this sheet is for the company I'm working for and they want to own the installable trigger. However, it appears that the prompt only shows up for the person who owns the trigger. If anyone else tries to edit the function and open the prompt. The following error shows up:
`You do not have permission to call prompt at emailPrompt(onEdit:54) at onEdit_sendEmail(onEdit:42) –`

So, now I have to figure out how to make it so that this trigger works for anyone who has access to the spreadsheet. Thanks!

Comment: functions triggered with simple triggers must finish within 30 seconds.  [Simple trigger restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Comment: You can try an installable trigger but pay attention to Ruben's warning in his answer below.

Comment: The error rate shows 100%. What errors have being logged on the executions page?

Comment: You do not have permission to call prompt
    at emailPrompt(onEdit:54)
    at onEdit_sendEmail(onEdit:42)

Comment: Strange as it's not even asking me to enable permissions as it usually does

Comment: Create a [mcve] and include more details like who is the spreadsheet owner, what kind of account are you using, if you have signed in into multiple accounts, what runtime are you using. Please avoid using reserved function names for naming files, etc. as doing that might lead to confussions.

Comment: Okay, I actually got it working by logging into my company's Gmail account (which owns the trigger). Is there any way to make it so that everyone else who doesn't own the trigger can run it without an issue?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify what you are asking or post a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple triggers have several limitations. Use an installable trigger instead.

NOTE: Don't use reserved function names (`onOpen`, `onEdit`, `onSelectionChange`, `doPost`, `doGet`, `onInstall`) for functions that will be called by installable triggers as some of these functions might be called twice for the same event and the others could be called by different events that might be confusing.