# Why does HTML output not run in a loop the same as a Prompt Response or Alert?

Tags: loops, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I currently have column A in the spreadsheet filled with checkboxes and have `getA1Notation()` used to grab this action when the user checks a box. I would then like to run an HTML dialog that has buttons to create an action for that row (HTML script not created yet, just running this test).

The issue I am running into is that when I put the HTML dialog box into a loop, it does not appear when the action (clicking on the checkbox) is done. I can replace the HTML dialog box with a prompt response or alert with buttons and it works perfect, but I would like to use an html box to have multiple custom buttons.

I am very new to using Apps Script for spreadsheets, so thank you for any help.

CODE:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  for (var counter = 0; counter <= 500; counter = counter + 1)
  {
    const a1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2+counter, 1).getA1Notation();
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() == a1)
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2+counter, 15).setValue('Hello'); //this is just to test the loop is working and doing this action anytime I click a checkbox
      var tester = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p>test</p").setWidth(250).setHeight(300);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(tester, "teest");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stop, don't use a simple trigger that use a loop to show a dialog / sidebar.

The above because simple triggers have limitations, i.e. they  have a shorter execution time limit, and they can't do some things that a function called from button / custom menu can do. They might be able to do certain tasks when the spreadsheet owner activates a trigger that might not work when a editor do the same.

By the other hand, `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(tester, "teest");` is asynchronous, meaning that after executing this statement the runtime will execute the next one immediately, it will not wait for the Google Sheets UI to load the dialog.

Related

- [Creating a Dialog Prompt Box from an onEdit Function isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62841779/1595451)

Comment: I didn't realize simple triggers were so limited compared to installable triggers. Switching over to an installable trigger solved my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### Assign a function to each row

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "your sheet name" && e.range.rowStart < rowactions.length) {
    const rowactions = ["","funk1","funk2","funk3"];//assigned functions
    executeFunctionByName(rowactions[e.range.rowStart])
  }
} 

function executeFunctionByName(func) {
  this[func]();
}
```

Probably need an installalble onedit.

Comment: I didn't realize simple triggers were so limited compared to installable triggers. Switching over to an installable trigger solved my issue. Thank you!

Comment: [simple trigger restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)